# Java: custom enum validator annotation not triggered in Spring RestControllerAdvice exception handler

Tags: java, spring, enums, aop

A custom enum validator annotation interface:

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PanTypeSubSetValidator.class)
public @interface PanTypeSubset {
    PanType[] anyOf();
    String message() default "must be any of {anyOf}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and the actual implementation:

```
public class PanTypeSubSetValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PanTypeSubset, PanType> {
    private PanType[] subset;

    @Override
    public void initialize(PanTypeSubset constraint) {
        this.subset = constraint.anyOf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(PanType value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value == null || Arrays.asList(subset).contains(value);
    }
}
```

and the usage inside a request DTO:

```
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PanBaseRequestDto {

    @NotNull(message = "'PANTYPE' cannot be empty or null")
    @PanTypeSubset(anyOf = {PanType.PAN, PanType.TOKEN}, message = "yesssss")
    private PanType panType;

}
```

The problem is that this annotation never seems to be triggered. I get another exception kick in in the @RestControllerAdvice DefaultExceptionHandler implementation before this actual validation:

```
Handling generic exception: (Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize value of type `...pantoken.PanType` from String "PAN1": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [TOKEN, PAN]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `...pantoken.PanType` from String "PAN1": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [TOKEN, PAN]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a custom `@JsonCreator` function inside the **ENUM** class. Not the best approach, as we loose the value that user has submitted when displaying error to the end client, but it's ok for me.

```
@JsonCreator
public static PanType create(String value) {
    if (Objects.isNull(value)) {
        return null;
    }

    return Arrays.stream(PanType.values())
            .filter(v -> value.equals(v.getType()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(PanType.UNKNOWN);
}
```